# How to remove Reply List option in Thunderbird 3?

Tags: email, thunderbird, mailing-lists, reply

I receive email as part of a mailing list that also CC's other people.  T-Bird defaults the toolbar button to Reply List instead of Reply All, which strips away the CC's.  That's bad, because they're not on the list.  Is there a way I can stop T-Bird from presenting Reply List as an option, or at least make Reply All the default?  Thanks!

EDIT: I'm talking about the original email's toolbar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original functionality was developed in [this enhancement ticket](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=45715) in which there was extensive discussion about how exactly this should work; there is a request in a [later follow-up issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=498448#c6) to do exactly what you say and make Reply All the default button when there are multiple recipients. There's an [extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/15029/) which is supposed to re-map the keys but not in the way you intend, and it would be possible to create an extension to do as you say, but as far as I can see nobody's done that yet.

You can work around the issue by creating a button or using keyboard shortcuts as others have suggested though.

Comment: the "extension" (15029) is a broken link

Comment: Also, `Ctrl+Shift+R` is the default keybinding for `Reply All` on Linux (similar on other platforms, see menu bar, _Message_); remembering this may be the fastest of the possible workarounds.

Answer (score 2):

It is not quite clear which toolbar you are referring to, the "mini toolbar" in the message header or the global toolbar.

The global Thunderbird toolbar can be customized to show a "Reply All" button which should do what you want:

- Right click on the toolbar
- Select **Customize...**
- Drag the **Reply All** button to the toolbar

Another possibility is to choose **Reply to All** from the context menu of the message. The context menu displays all reply option **Reply to Sender Only**, **Reply to List** and **Reply to All**.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a Thunderbird extension for this purpose: [Disable "reply list"](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/disable-reply-list/)

Comment: Would be great if it made it non-default instead of disabling it entirely.

Answer (score 1):

The [CompactHeader extension for Thunderbird](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/compactheader/) allows customizing the buttons in the message pane to have a permanent Reply-All button either instead of or as well as the Reply-List/All/etc. popup.

[image: CompactHeader toolbar customization panel (image from addons.mozilla.org screenshots)]

Answer (score 0):

A keyboard solution to assign a shortcut key to reply-all : [KeyConfig extension for Thunderbird](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Keyconfig_extension:_Thunderbird)

> Allows you to customize the keyboard
>   shortcuts. One application of this is
>   to reassign the Thunderbird keyboard
>   shortcuts to mimic Microsoft Outlook.
>   (alt+w = forward email, ctrl+r =
>   reply, ctrl+l = reply to all). Once
>   KeyConfig is installed, you access it
>   from Tools --> KeyConfig. The "reply"
>   setting is found in "Reply to
>   Newsgroup".

<sup>[source](http://mediocrepolymath.blogspot.com/2010/04/make-thunderbird-3-run-like-outlook.html)</sup>